# How to assign a value to a variable using CJavascriptExpression in yii

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii, yii-extensions

I am using yii and I am using CJuiAutocomplete. I am trying to create a **dynamic source** in the widget but unable to do so. So i need help in the following issue. Here is the code

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete',array(
    'name'=>'search Type',
    'source'=>new CJavaScriptExpression("function(){
               var name=$('#myname').val();
               if(name==='ajeet')
               {
               $.ajax({
              url: 'http://localhost/exhibition/admin/exhibitors/default/target',
              data: {
              list: 'exhibitor'
                        },
              type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){

                // how to assign the result i.e data to the source

                    }
                        });
                }   
                }"),
    'options'=>array(
        'minLength'=>'1',
        'select'=>'js:function(){
            alert("ajeet");
            }'
    ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'style'=>'height: 20px;',
    ),
));
```

The server is sending the desired result as i have checked it many times.So the server script has no errors.
**Question:-** As I have used the CJavascriptExpression and using it for the first time, I do not know how to assign the value return by it to the **source**. I am getting the desired result from Ajax in the success part **but do not know how to use it or assign it to the source.**
**Note:-** I have already tried using `return data;`

Comment: Do you try options `sourceUrl => 'http://localhost/exhibition/admin/exhibitors/default/target'`?

Comment: Also check autocomplete manual: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source `Function: The third variation, a callback, provides the most flexibility and can be used to connect any data source to Autocomplete. The callback gets two arguments:`

Answer (score -1):

I think you have something wrong in you coding.especially the **source** part

you can refer below tutorial, how they do it
http://chevronscode.com/example-of-yii-autocomplete.html